# How to get the private key from .pem file using JJWT

Tags: java, jwt, jjwt

I have [JJWT](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/blob/master/README.md#jws-key-create-secret) library integrated java project. And now I have a .PEM file which includes my RSA private key. How can I read the .PEM file and get the private key using `JJWT` library?

Comment: providing a sample of your code and more information, you will get better answers to your question. I highly recommend reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of answers you receive.

Comment: there is a method `Jwtbuilder::signWith(Key)`. Just search SO on how to read private key from file and pass this key to this method...

Comment: Have a look at this [Generating a JWT using an existing private key and RS256 algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52464921/418693). The linked answer solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't support `.pem` files natively. [See this issue](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/issues/131).

[See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787571/how-to-read-pem-file-to-get-private-and-public-key) how to read `.pem` files in Java.

Comment: Good find, but you should flag as duplicate instead of linking there.