# i have public key as a text file and want to give it to a function that accepts publickey not string

Tags: java, types, private-key

helo. any help can be hopeful please. it's about 1 month that i am tring to solve the problem.
i have below private key by size 2048 and a function to sign some data.

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

hear is the function

```
public static String getSignedText(
        String text, String algorithm, PrivateKey privateKey) 
          throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException { 
      byte[] data = text.getBytes("UTF8"); 
      Signature sig = Signature.getInstance(algorithm == null ? "SHA256WITHRSA" : algorithm); 
      sig.initSign(privateKey); 
      sig.update(data); 
      byte[] signatureBytes = sig.sign(); 
      return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signatureBytes); 
}
```

i have tried some string to privatekey functions but non of them can convert the string key to privatekey type

Comment: Please tag the question with the programming language you are using... it looks like Java to me but I don't know.

Comment: I've now seen this apparently malformed (according to lapo.it) ASN.1 private key format at least 3 times. Where is it coming from?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: I don't see anything malformed (either in lapo.it or local openssl asn1parse), although lapo.it doesn't seem to have -- at least it doesn't offer me in the pulldown -- PKCS8-unencrypted, which is the (only) correct definition for this PEM-type (see RFC7468 section 10).

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: yes that dupe is better focussed on the specific issue than the ones my search found -- even though it should have matched my criteria. I've have had this problem before, where Stack's search doesn't find posts that exist and are good matches. I may give up using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's used with a public-key-cryptography *algorithm*, that's a private key (as the labels say) not a public key. It is *almost* in the format used by Java crypto: it is PKCS8 and unencrypted, but is [PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) rather than 'DER' (binary). To un-PEM you need to remove the BEGIN and END lines, and decode the base64 to binary with the linebreaks either removed or ignored. You then put the result in [`PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/spec/PKCS8EncodedKeySpec.html) and feed it to the `.generatePrivate` method of a [`KeyFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyFactory.html) for the correct algorithm, which is `"RSA"`.

I'm certain I've seen this case posted at least a dozen times, but on searching I can find only two decent duplicates; see
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48173910/2868801 (but note Java 9 up moves `javax.xml.bind` outside of 'base', so using `java.util.Base64` instead may be more convenient)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66362542/2868801 (but skip the parts about JJWT, and note it assumes *all* linebreaks have been removed -- on the BEGIN and END lines and on the base64)

Comment: thanks alot. it worked. you saved the day for me.  as you sed i removed line break and begin/end private.... and after 1 month by your help it worked  :)))))))).